# Visual Studio 2017 - Emulators Disappeared

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2017, windows-10-universal

Yesterday I've installed

- Windows 10 Fall Creators Update SDK (ver. 10.0.16299.15),
- Microsoft Mobile Emulator for Windows 10 (ver. 15254.1)

After installing new SDK, my emulators are completely gone from Run Button. Even local machine. I have Visual Studio 2017 (ver. 15.4.1).
Second thing is when I run Visual Studio Installer I see required things for SDKs and emulators are checked.

SDK and Mobile Emulator versions are confusing me. Also, I tired repairing Visual Studio but no luck.

Edit: All that's listed on the Run Button is 'Start' and 'Download new emulators' *(not even local machine)*.

Thanks for your help.

**UPDATE**

[image]

I have 4 projects in solution. 1 UWP project, 2 Class Library projects and 1 project for Test. They all have same Target/min version (as you can see in picture).

Also, installed SDKs and emulators

SDKs

- Windows 10.0.16299.15
- Windows 10.0.15063.468
- Windows 10.0.15063.137
- Windows 10.0.14393.795
- Windows 10.0.14393.33
- Windows 10.0.10586.212

Emulators

- HoloLens Emulator 10.0.14393.0
- HoloLens Emulator Image 10.0.14393.0
- Emulator 10.0.15254.1
- Emulator 10.0.15063.137
- Emulator 10.0.14393.0
- Mobile Image 10.0.15254.0
- Mobile Image 10.0.15063.0
- Mobile Image 10.0.14393.0

Thanks again.

Comment: Are you creating a UWP app? Commonly  a UWP app will not show run button as `Start`. If you do create a UWP app, could you please provide the target and min versions for your app? And what's the solution platform target? If conveniently, screenshots required for your scenario.

Comment: Hello, thanks for interesting.I will update my question with screenshots and needed information. (By the way app was (UWP) created way before the latest Windows 10 update which is 16299)

Comment: Could you please open the Visual Studio and create a new blank UWP app and check the result ? If you change the start project several times, did the run button changed?

Comment: I created a new blank UWP app but the result was same. I did change the start project several times, also target/min version but no fix.

Comment: Should I check Hyper V? Or reinstall SDKs?

Comment: Did your windows is home edition? Have you tried repair the Visual Studio?

Comment: My Windows OS is Pro edition. Also I tried repairing VS, still same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I did clean install for VS2017. Deleted every piece of VS app. Re-installed. Worked.

Comment: I have the same problem and this didn't fix it for me.

Comment: @lesscode well, the solution is complicated and there are many ways to fix it. Some solutions work and some of them don't.

Answer (score 1):

The issue may be caused by the Minimum version setting in the UWP project.
Go to the Project Properties > Application tab > Targeting area and adjust the Min version. This will cause the solution to close and reopen. Check the Run menu when it reopens.

See [Run menu isn't offering Windows 10 Mobile Emulator despite being installed](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/67394/run-menu-isnt-offering-windows-10-mobile-emulator.html)

Here is another explanation of what is going on and what you can do about it.

[Windows 10 mobile emulator (ver. 15254) not available for UWP/.NET Core/Xamarin project debugging](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/153076/windows-10-mobile-emulator-ver-15254-not-available.html)